# If statements and Variables

Tags: python

I am new to Python and assistance is needed with the following exercise:

Exercise 3.1 The cover price of a book is $24.95, but bookstores get a 40 percent discount.Shipping costs $3 for the first copy and 75 cents for each additional copy. Calculate the total wholesale costs for 60 copies.

I am trying to figure out code that gives you the total discounted price along with shipping fees based off of the input.

```
book = 14.97


print("How many books", end='')
print (float (input()) * book + (.75 * 59 )+3)
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What is your question ? Add code snippet.

Comment: I am trying to make a code that calculates the total wholesale price for books purchased by the user. The price of a book is $24.95 but is discounted at 40% per book , the shipping is $3.00 for the first book, and $0.75 per additional copy.

Answer (score 0):

You must clarify your question, and ask for code not for solution of a problem.

You probably have to define function to do the calculation:

```
def cost(num_of_books):
    book_price = 14.97
    discount = 0.4

    # Price without shipping
    price = book_price * (1-discount) * num_of_books

    # Adding shipping
    total_price = price + 0.75*(num_of_books -1) + 3
    return total_price
```